# random.choice() equivalent in order

Tags: python, list, function, random, iteration

I know using for loops display the items in a list in order, but it only displays them at once.

e.g.:

```
>>> list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in list:
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
```

Same if I do it with range and length, regarding indexes.

But what random.choice() does is taking a random item in the list and then printing it each time the function is called.

e.g.:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print(choice(list))
1
>>> print(choice(list))
5
>>> print(choice(list))
4
```

Is there an equivalent to random.choice() but for printing the items in lists in order each time it is required?

Like:

```
>>> list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print(function(list))
1
>>> print(function(list))
2
>>> print(function(list))
3
```

And so on until the last item in the list is printed, for the list to go back to the first index again in the next print.

Comment: The implicit global state involved in the API you propose is a usability nightmare and a massive source of bugs. Just keep track of the index yourself, or use an explicit iterator.

Comment: I really don't understand in what sense this is equivalent to random choice.

Comment: Equivalent in result.

Comment: It's not equivalent in result at all, though.

Comment: *And so on.* - and so on how? What would happen at the 6th call of `print(function(list))`,? Would you want to provide a restart function too?

Comment: Oh, thanks for noticing that! I meant to say that, when the last call comes, it goes back to the first index. I'll add that to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to create an iterator for the values in the list. Then use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to access the next element.

```
values = [1, 2, 4, 8]
data = iter(values)
print(next(data))
print(next(data))
```

You will get a `StopIteration` error when you try to call `next` after you've already got the last element.

Since `iter` creates an iterator you can't go back in the sequence. If you want to start again from the beginning you'd have to create a new iterator with `data = iter(values)`.

If you want to repeat the data after you reached the last value you can use [`itertools.cyle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

```
from itertools import cycle
values = [1, 2, 4, 8]
data = iter(cycle((values))
print(next(data))
print(next(data))  # repeat this as often as you like
```

Caveat: Don't try to build a list from that iterator, because it's unlimited.

Comment: I imagine that, if implemented on a function, you can use an if to get back to the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: To go back to the beginning just do `data = iter(values)` again.

Comment: @idkman No, if implemented in a function you cannot use an if to get back to the beginning.  An `iter` object is ***consumed*** when you use it, either by explicit iteration or using the `next` function.  Maybe Matthias could clarify this aspect in their answer.

Comment: Oooh, interesting! Thanks for the clarification and answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own.
A while loop will rerun the iteration of the numbers as long as you need.
Yield x is saying ‘returning this value, but when called again, I will start from where I left off.

Edit: gotta catch empty lists.

```
def loop(lst):
    if lst:
        while True:
            for x in lst:
                yield x
```

Comment: `from itertools import cycle`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll try that.

Comment: `cycle` has a 1.5 steps trickier suggestion with making a list for itself, and putting the empty-check into the `while`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for telling that.